github-actions: a multi-line output from a previous step with 'uses' in a next step of a workflow
I do not understand, how to collect all of the output from previous step that implemented as uses to public it as a PR comment in the next step of the workflow.
There are many answers about collecting a multi-line output using variables, $GITHUB_OUTPUT, &GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY, echo <<EOF etc, but for that the own script need to be used.
My script is:
name: check-pep8
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  check-pep8:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      checks: write
      pull-requests: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Run PEP-8 check
        id: pep8-action
        continue-on-error: true
        uses: quentinguidee/pep8-action@v1
        with:
          arguments: '--max-line-length=120'

      - name: Comment PR
        if: steps.pep8-action.status != 'success'
        uses: thollander/actions-comment-pull-request@v3
        with:
          message: |
            ${{ join(steps.pep8-action.outputs.output, ' ') }}

The full output of the step pep8-action is
./corpora_deduplication.py:42:15: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)
./corpora_deduplication.py:47:41: E222 multiple spaces after operator
./corpora_deduplication.py:47:41: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
./corpora_deduplication.py:47:121: E501 line too long (145 > 120 characters)
./corpora_deduplication.py:48:81: E702 multiple statements on one line (semicolon)
./corpora_deduplication.py:48:121: E501 line too long (163 > 120 characters)
./corpora_deduplication.py:61:3: E271 multiple spaces after keyword
./corpora_deduplication.py:61:13: E225 missing whitespace around operator
Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
./corpora_deduplication.py:47:41: E222 multiple spaces after operator
./corpora_deduplication.py:47:41: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
./corpora_deduplication.py:47:121: E501 line too long (145 > 120 characters)
./corpora_deduplication.py:48:81: E702 multiple statements on one line (semicolon)
./corpora_deduplication.py:48:121: E501 line too long (163 > 120 characters)
./corpora_deduplication.py:61:3: E271 multiple spaces after keyword
./corpora_deduplication.py:61:13: E225 missing whitespace around operator

I see the only first line in the steps.pep8-action.outputs.output:
{
"exit-code": "1",
"output": "./corpora_deduplication.py:42:15: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)"
}

Is there any work-around for that?

The way the action is written (see here) results in only the first line of the PEP8 output being set as an action output. You have to use another linter action, unless the one you use gets updated.

Thanks to Benjamin W. for his notice.
I went the other way and did everything according to the documentation.
# Install Python dependencies, run tests and lint Python code
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-python
name: Python package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  checks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      checks: write
      pull-requests: write

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        # Semantic version range syntax or exact version of a Python version
        python-version: '3.x'
        # Optional - x64 or x86 architecture, defaults to x64
        architecture: 'x64'
        # Cache all dependencies
        cache: 'pip'

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m  pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m  pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    
    - name: Lint with flake8
      continue-on-error: true
      id: pep8-action
      run: |
        {
          # Keep the multi-line output
          echo 'output<<EOF'
          # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
          flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --exit-zero
          echo ---
          # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings
          flake8 . --count --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=120 --exit-zero
          echo EOF
        } >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

    - name: Comment PR
      if: ${{ contains(steps.pep8-action.outputs.output, 'py') }}
      uses: thollander/actions-comment-pull-request@v3
      with:
        message: |
          ${{ join(steps.pep8-action.outputs.output, ' ') }}

    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest

    - name: Lint check is failed
      if: ${{ contains(steps.pep8-action.outputs.output, 'py') }}
      run: exit 1

